Why is my DataLoader process using up to 2.6GB of virtual memory, and is there any way to reduce it?
Why is my DataLoader process using up to 2.6GB of virtual memory, and is there any way to reduce it?
Each DataLoader process takes up 2.6GB of virtual memory, and 4 processes take up 10.4GB.
    from transformers import AutoModelForZeroShotImageClassification, AutoProcessor
    ...
    dataset = ImageDataset(image, clip_processor, SCAN_PROCESS_BATCH_SIZE, test_times)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=SCAN_PROCESS_BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=4)

from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image, processor, scan_process_batch_size, test_times):
        self.image = image
        self.processor = processor
        self.scan_process_batch_size = scan_process_batch_size
        self.test_times = test_times

    def __len__(self):
        return self.scan_process_batch_size * self.test_times

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Use processor to process images
        inputs = self.processor(
            images=[self.image],
            return_tensors="pt",
            padding=True
        )['pixel_values']
        return inputs


I looked at the memory bar through process hacker software, and there were a large number of 32MB rows in the private column, and i save it and find there were all 0 in this 32MB memory.

i find that the virtual memory increases after there code.
        for i in range(self._num_workers):
            # No certainty which module multiprocessing_context is
            index_queue = multiprocessing_context.Queue()  # type: ignore[var-annotated]
            # Need to `cancel_join_thread` here!
            # See sections (2) and (3b) above.
            index_queue.cancel_join_thread()
            w = multiprocessing_context.Process(
                target=_utils.worker._worker_loop,
                args=(self._dataset_kind, self._dataset, index_queue,
                      self._worker_result_queue, self._workers_done_event,
                      self._auto_collation, self._collate_fn, self._drop_last,
                      self._base_seed, self._worker_init_fn, i, self._num_workers,
                      self._persistent_workers, self._shared_seed))
            w.daemon = True
            # NB: Process.start() actually take some time as it needs to
            #     start a process and pass the arguments over via a pipe.
            #     Therefore, we only add a worker to self._workers list after
            #     it started, so that we do not call .join() if program dies
            #     before it starts, and __del__ tries to join but will get:
            #     AssertionError: can only join a started process.
            w.start()
            self._index_queues.append(index_queue)
            self._workers.append(w)


I would expect that reducing the num_workers would decrease the memory usage. For example num_workers=1 should only use 1/4 of the memory. Keep in mind this also reduces parallelization as you will be using less CPU cores/threads.
Another factor is the batch size. The code snippet contains batch_size=SCAN_PROCESS_BATCH_SIZE, I'm not sure what this value is declared as but reducing it will reduce the number of images loaded into memory.
Without seeing the rest of the code and inputs it's difficult to find any other reductions. One thing to look at would be the size of the input images and whether that could be reduced (e.g by a scaling image transform).
